# International Transfer

Tags: international-transfer

If you are transfering funds in excess of 1 Million U.S. dollars from a foreign account to the U.S., is there the need for an internation funds transfer permit?

Comment: Are you being asked to pay for one in order to get millions of dollars wired to your account from someone who contacted you via email?

Comment: To extend what @Shawaron is saying, if someone emailed you saying "You won the lottery! You'll just need to pay $500 for this permit first." **they are a scammer and you have not won the lottery** (or the inheritance of Robert Mugabe, or any of the hundreds of other variations on this scam).